# Extremely slow DB query even after increasing CPU and RAM of Droplet

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-performance

I have a single database query which runs when a user searches a product on my site.
I have increased the Digital Ocean Droplet size from 1GB to 4GB package but still the restuls are not satisfactory.

While doing the tests with [BlazeMeter](http://blazemeter.com) and running myTop i came up with the below analysis.

1GB Ram[image]

2GB Ram
[image]

4GB Ram
[image]

8GB Ram
[image]

The error rate is decreased but still the average respose is too slow.
Below is the query which i managed to get using myTop command. Can some one help me top optimize it ? Thanks in advance .

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  p.*,
                m.logo as market_logo,
                m.slug as market_slug,
                c.id as cat_id,
                c.slug as cat_slug,
                c.name as category_name,
                c.name_ar as category_name_ar,
                sub.slug as sub_slug,
                sub.id as subcat_id,
                sub.name as subcategory_name,
                sub.name_ar as subcategory_name_ar,
                f.desc as descp_en,
                f.desc_ar as descp_ar
        FROM    category as c,
                sub_category as sub,
                promotion AS p,
                flyer AS f,
                market as m
        WHERE   c.id=p.category AND
                sub.id=p.sub_category AND
                f.market_id=m.id AND
                f.id=p.flyer_id AND
                f.active=1 AND 1 AND 1 AND 1 AND 1 AND
                p.product_name_en LIKE '%a%'
        ORDER BY
                p.price ASC
        ) DUMMY_ALIAS1
UNION
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  p.*,
                m.logo as market_logo,
                m.slug as market_slug,
                c.id as cat_id,
                c.slug as cat_slug,
                c.name as category_name,
                c.name_ar as category_name_ar,
                sub.slug as sub_slug,
                sub.id as subcat_id,
                sub.name as subcategory_name,
                sub.name_ar as subcategory_name_ar,
                f.desc as descp_en,
                f.desc_ar as descp_ar
        FROM    category as c,
                sub_category as sub,
                promotion AS p,
                flyer AS f,
                market as m
        WHERE   c.id=p.category AND
                sub.id=p.sub_category AND
                f.market_id=m.id AND
                f.id=p.flyer_id AND
                f.active=1 AND 1 AND 1 AND 1 AND 1 AND
                sub.name LIKE '%a%'
        ORDER BY
                p.price ASC
        ) DUMMY_ALIAS2
UNION
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  p.*,
                m.logo as market_logo,
                m.slug as market_slug,
                c.id as cat_id,
                c.slug as cat_slug,
                c.name as category_name,
                c.name_ar as category_name_ar,
                sub.slug as sub_slug,
                sub.id as subcat_id,
                sub.name as subcategory_name,
                sub.name_ar as subcategory_name_ar,
                f.desc as descp_en,
                f.desc_ar as descp_ar
        FROM    category as c,
                sub_category as sub,
                promotion AS p,
                flyer AS f,
                market as m
        WHERE   c.id=p.category AND
                sub.id=p.sub_category AND
                f.market_id=m.id AND
                f.id=p.flyer_id AND
                f.active=1 AND 1 AND 1 AND 1 AND 1 AND
                p.product SOUNDS LIKE '%a%'
        ORDER BY
                p.price ASC
        ) DUMMY_ALIAS3
```

This is the output of EXPLAIN:

```
*** row 1 ***
          table:  <derived2>
           type:  ALL
  possible_keys:  NULL
            key:  NULL
        key_len:  NULL
            ref:  NULL
           rows:  4525
          Extra:  NULL
*** row 2 ***
          table:  p
           type:  ALL
  possible_keys:  NULL
            key:  NULL
        key_len:  NULL
            ref:  NULL
           rows:  240072
          Extra:  Using where; Using filesort
*** row 3 ***
          table:  sub
           type:  eq_ref
  possible_keys:  PRIMARY
            key:  PRIMARY
        key_len:  4
            ref:  mywebsite.p.sub_category
           rows:  1
          Extra:  Using where
*** row 4 ***
          table:  f
           type:  eq_ref
  possible_keys:  PRIMARY
            key:  PRIMARY
        key_len:  4
            ref:  mywebsite.p.flyer_id
           rows:  1
          Extra:  Using where
*** row 5 ***
          table:  m
           type:  eq_ref
  possible_keys:  PRIMARY
            key:  PRIMARY
        key_len:  4
            ref:  mywebsite.f.market_id
           rows:  1
          Extra:  NULL
*** row 6 ***
          table:  c
           type:  eq_ref
  possible_keys:  PRIMARY
            key:  PRIMARY
        key_len:  4
            ref:  mywebsite.p.category
           rows:  1
          Extra:  Using where
*** row 7 ***
          table:  <derived4>
           type:  ALL
  possible_keys:  NULL
            key:  NULL
        key_len:  NULL
            ref:  NULL
           rows:  2925
          Extra:  NULL
*** row 8 ***
          table:  p
           type:  ALL
  possible_keys:  NULL
            key:  NULL
        key_len:  NULL
            ref:  NULL
           rows:  240072
          Extra:  Using filesort
*** row 9 ***
          table:  sub
           type:  eq_ref
  possible_keys:  PRIMARY
            key:  PRIMARY
        key_len:  4
            ref:  mywebsite.p.sub_category
           rows:  1
          Extra:  Using where
*** row 10 ***
          table:  f
           type:  eq_ref
  possible_keys:  PRIMARY
            key:  PRIMARY
        key_len:  4
            ref:  mywebsite.p.flyer_id
           rows:  1
          Extra:  Using where
*** row 11 ***
          table:  m
           type:  eq_ref
  possible_keys:  PRIMARY
            key:  PRIMARY
        key_len:  4
            ref:  mywebsite.f.market_id
           rows:  1
          Extra:  NULL
*** row 12 ***
          table:  c
           type:  eq_ref
  possible_keys:  PRIMARY
            key:  PRIMARY
        key_len:  4
            ref:  mywebsite.p.category
           rows:  1
          Extra:  Using where
*** row 13 ***
          table:  <derived6>
           type:  system
  possible_keys:  NULL
            key:  NULL
        key_len:  NULL
            ref:  NULL
           rows:  NULL
          Extra:  const row not found
*** row 14 ***
          table:  p
           type:  ALL
  possible_keys:  NULL
            key:  NULL
        key_len:  NULL
            ref:  NULL
           rows:  240072
          Extra:  Using where; Using filesort
*** row 15 ***
          table:  sub
           type:  eq_ref
  possible_keys:  PRIMARY
            key:  PRIMARY
        key_len:  4
            ref:  mywebsite.p.sub_category
           rows:  1
          Extra:  Using where
*** row 16 ***
          table:  f
           type:  eq_ref
  possible_keys:  PRIMARY
            key:  PRIMARY
        key_len:  4
            ref:  mywebsite.p.flyer_id
           rows:  1
          Extra:  Using where
*** row 17 ***
          table:  m
           type:  eq_ref
  possible_keys:  PRIMARY
            key:  PRIMARY
        key_len:  4
            ref:  mywebsite.f.market_id
           rows:  1
          Extra:  NULL
*** row 18 ***
          table:  c
           type:  eq_ref
  possible_keys:  PRIMARY
            key:  PRIMARY
        key_len:  4
            ref:  mywebsite.p.category
           rows:  1
          Extra:  Using where
*** row 19 ***
          table:  <union1,3,5>
           type:  ALL
  possible_keys:  NULL
            key:  NULL
        key_len:  NULL
            ref:  NULL
           rows:  NULL
          Extra:  NULL
```

Comment: Is this a generated query by some ORM? Do you have the possibility of change it? Why `UNION`? Why wrap `selects` into `select * `? What is the purpose of `AND 1 AND 1 AND 1 AND 1`? This query can be written in one single select. I can rewrite that quickly if you want but still you're doing `LIKE "%a%"` which is always going to result in full table scan but at least you will have only 1 filesort instead of 3.

Comment: @KárolyNagy Thank you for your quick reply. What we are trying to achieve here is let's say you are searching for "apple" in a supermarket near your home and it gives you "apple jam" , "Yellow apple", "egyptian apple" etc results. What I want now is to sort by price, first match of products which starts with "apple" and then sort again 2nd match which has apple in the middle of the string and then again sort by price 3rd match. Hope i made it clear.

Comment: I would suggest that MySQL is not the best tool for the job here. You can hammer a nail in with a screwdriver if you hit it really hard. My suggestion is to look at a product such as solr or elasticsearch.

Comment: @eroomydna , but solar is good for full body search. My promotion table has only the promotion name and product name fields related to my search. ( others are not related for search ) . Still you think i should go for Solr ? I have used solr for a Recipes Site built with Drupal and it helped in showing most relevant results related to "Chicken" for example, by searching all NODES ( pages ) text... In my case now, i need to show promotions, for example, "Apple" to user which are cheap, then i can add the promotion to the results which are for example "The Best Apple"(if user searched for Apple)

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to index your queries otherwise it's always going to be slow and scaling the server will not really help much due to the amount of data it has to read on every full table scan.

**Option #1**

I would suggest (if you want to keep everything in MySQL) to build a term index:

1) you need two more tables

```
CREATE TABLE `term` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`term` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `term` (`term`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `promotion_term` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`term_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`promotion_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`num` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
-- the position of the first occurrence of the term in the promotion (for example: 'apple yellow apple' -> 0)
`position` smallint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `promotion_term_unique` (`term_id`,`promotion_id `)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

2) Populate your data and keep it up to date

This can be done from your application, cronjob or trigger in mysql. Whichever you feel safe with.

3) Change your query to something like this

```
SELECT  p.*, ...
FROM promotion AS p
JOIN product_term AS pt ON pt.promotion_id = p.id
JOIN term AS t on t.id = pt.term_id
JOIN ...
WHERE t.term LIKE 'a%'  
-- Mind the prefix search instead of %a% (this take advantage of indexes)
...
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY pt.position, -- Order by position brings promotions to top which has apple as the first word, then comes where it is the second and so on
    p.price
```

You can also include `sum(num)` which will give you the possibility to order by relevance.

To read more about this you can take a look on a benchmark I did with MySQL Full text search alternatives: http://charlesnagy.info/it/mysql/full-text-search-in-mysql

**Option #2**

You can use some search engines which provides great full text search capabilities out of the box like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch).

A very simple solution for what you want is to use the facet and facet filter with parameters like this:

```
/solr/select?q=*&facet=on&facet.prefix=a&facet.field=text&wt=json&omitHeader=true&facet.limit=5&rows=0&facet.mincount=1'
```

More on this and how to set it up with Nginx: [Typeahead and autosuggest with pure Solr and Nginx](http://charlesnagy.info/it/typeahead-and-autosuggest-with-pure-solr-and-nginx)

**Option #3**

You can use also redis for prefix match using [ZRANGEBYLEX](http://redis.io/commands/ZRANGEBYLEX). That is quite limited compared to the previous options but also a way to implement autosuggest.